# How can I format this date into Day - Month - Year

Tags: python

```
def UpdateDate(WorstDate):
    Day = WorstDate[5:]
    Month = WorstDate[2:6]
    Year = WorstDate[:2]
    return Day + "-" + Month + "-" + Year
print(UpdateDate("202011Jan"))
```

I keep getting (1Jan-2011-20)
I'm no pro so any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: what do you want the output to be?

Comment: Is there any reason you’re not using existing date/time related functionality? Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: You might find the following article useful: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the updated solution:

```
    def UpdateDate(WorstDate):
        Day = WorstDate[4:6]
        Month = WorstDate[6:]
        Year = WorstDate[:4]
        return Day + "-" + Month + "-" + Year

    print(UpdateDate("202011Jan"))
```

Output:

`11-Jan-2020`

Comment: I wish I understood how this ratio/list/brackets thing work but it worked.. Thank you. I had to change it to [4:6] but it certainly worked.

Comment: @NewPythonLearner the "ratio/list/brackets thing" is called "string slicing" https://www.pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/

Comment: @NewPythonLearner What ratios?

Answer (score 1):

This might be useful:

```
import time

timestr = time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")

print(timestr)
```

Comment: I agree on that. NewPythonLearner should consider adding it to his code to make it leaner. @AMC if you could vote it up, would be great.

Comment: This would be good but my professor does not want it like that.